# Jenkins CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS plugin variable is empty

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have installed the *Changes Since Last Success* Plugin for Jenkins jobs. Inside the Build step of a Jenkins job I am trying to echo the value of the `CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS` variable. Unfortunately there is no value for this variable. I echo this value into a file inside my job's workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You need **[Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)** instead.

*Changes Since Last Success* plugin has nothing to do with the *CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS* variable.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Changes+Since+Last+Success+Plugin

```
This plugin adds a build action to aggregate changes from all previous builds to the last successful one. The primary goal is to generate a changelog to be used for continuous delivery, as an aggregate for all changes since the last deployable artifact. 

Additionally, this plugin can be used to generate a changelog for an arbitrary range of builds:...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i think i have solved my problem in another way, without using this plugin. Again, thanks for the effort!